# How to delete all rows except those belonging to more than one group

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataset "df" as below

How to delete all rows except those belonging to groups "b" and "d" (or those belonging to any combination of two or three groups)?

I know how to do it if I had to keep only one group, but cannot figure out how to keep more than one.

For example, with grep function I could do

```r
df <- df[grep("b", df$group),]
```

But again, how to keep more than just one group (suppose via using grep)?

[image]

Comment: `df[grep("b|d", df$group),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting specific groups, `%in%` is more specific than `grep()`/`grepl()`.

```
df[df$group %in% c('a', 'c'), ]
```

or

```
subset(df, group %in% c('a', 'c'))
```

Comment: dude, what if I want to delete groups 'a' and  'c', instead of keeping them? Could you please suggest this?

Comment: `df[!df$group %in% c('a', 'c'), ]` or `subset(df, !group %in% c('a', 'c'))` (etc. for data tables).